# Diffrent node number in mini_batch

Tags: python, pytorch-geometric, self-attention

I am fairly new to graph neural networks and I am training a GNN model using self attention and I have a few questions.

The question is my node count and node_num differs in each batch such that in the first batch I have:

Batch(batch=[1181], edge_attr=[1975, 3], edge_index=[2, 1975], x=[1181, 300])

in the second batch I have:
batch=[1134], edge_attr=[1635, 3], edge_index=[2, 1635], x=[1134, 300]

There were 1181 nodes in batch1, whereas 1134 nodes in batch2

When I tried to calculate self attention between nodes, I encountered the following problem

Here's how self attention works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P1tK.png)

the Q, W, K calculate as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63W4c.png)

the dimension of wq, wk, wv is

self.w_1 = Param(torch.Tensor(self.nodes_num, self.nodes_num))

So the problem I have is this

in batch1 , the the dimension of wq, wk, wv is self.w_q = Param(torch.Tensor(1181, 1181))
in batch2 , the the dimension of wq, wk, wv is self.w_q = Param(torch.Tensor(1134, 1134))
Dimensions vary with the number of nodes, causing w_q to be constantly redefined

Is this equivalent to using only one batch of samples for the model?

If so, how can I solve the problem?